# Array of values from the same radio button group

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm making a website in Laravel where user needs to enter his pseudonym, and on the settings page he can add multiple pseudonyms with jQuery. When he clicks the plus button, a text field, radio button and minus fields are added.

**Radio buttons** are there to mark one of those nicknames as default.

[Image: screenshot of how the inputs look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5VHM.png)

How do I pass an array of values out of those radio buttons? ie, if I selected 3rd out of 4 pseudonyms to be default:

```
{'0' => null, '1' => null, '2' => '1', '3'=> null}
```

So I can merge this array into pseudonyms array to be like:

```
{'0' => {'0' => 'John Doe', '1' => null},
'1' => {'0' => 'John Smith', '1' => null},
'2' => {'0' => 'John Wayne', '1' => '1'},
'3' => {'0' => 'John X', '1' => null}}
```

Finally, I would save it like this, or some other method that would also check if already existent and then update, but that's not important right now:

```
    foreach($pseudonyms as $pseudonym)
        $user->pseudonyms()->create(['name' => $pseudonym[0], 'status' => $pseudonym[1]]);
```

I'm probably just inexperienced and don't know some html/php basics that will let me do that, but what can I do :)

Anyway, here's the Blade part where inputs are:

```
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {!! Form::text('pseudonyms[]', null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {!! Form::radio('default[]', 1, null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>',['class'=>'btn btn-default add_field']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the part of jQuery that appends the additional fields in .input_fields_wrap

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap .row"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID

    var added_fields = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(added_fields < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="added"><div class="col-md-8 class1"><input type="text" name="pseudonyms[]" class="form-control"/></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-2 class2" ><input type="radio" name="default[]" value="1" class="form-control"/></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-2 class3" ><input type="button" value="-" class="remove_field btn btn-default add_field fa fa-minus"></div></div>'); //add input box
            added_fields++; //text box increment
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.added').remove();
        added_fields--;
    })
});
```

Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, solution was working on something else, coming back and having an answer after 2 minutes thinking about it. Created new array with a key from the radio button's value, so I could merge it with the other array with

```
    foreach($request->pseudonyms as $key => $value)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $default))
        {
            $pseudonyms[$key] = array($value, $default[$key]);
        } else {
            $pseudonyms[$key] = array($value, null);
        }
    }
```